# Twig with Symfony 2 displaying json encoded variables different between prod and dev

Tags: php, json, symfony, escaping, twig

We're building a Symfony 2 application that sends some data from controller to view:

### Controller

```
$user = array(
    'configuration' => array(
        'levels' => array(
            'warning' => 0.05,
            'danger'  => 0.10,
        ),
    ),
);

return $this->render(
    'MyWebsiteBundle:Core:searchResults.html.twig',
    array(
        'userJSON'  => json_encode($user)
    )
);
```

### View

```
<script language="javascript">
    user = $.parseJSON("{{ userJSON }}");
</script>
```

### Result

On `dev` the result looks like this and works as expected:

```
user = $.parseJSON("\x7B\x22configuration\x22\x3A\x7B\x22levels\x22\x3A\x7B\x22warning\x22\x3A0.05,\x22danger\x22\x3A0.1\x7D\x7D\x7D");
```

On the other hand, on `prod` the result is encoded in a different manner, thus displaying errors in console:

```
user = $.parseJSON("{&quot;configuration&quot;:{&quot;levels&quot;:{&quot;warning&quot;:0.05,&quot;danger&quot;:0.1}}}");
```

**Console Error**: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

What generates this difference?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Edit:** Also check @Lulhum's solution below. Up-vote it if it's better so I will select it as the correct answer.

The "problem" was Twig autoescaping variables. I used Twig's `raw` filter to skip autoescaping like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    user = $.parseJSON('{{ userJSON | raw }}');
</script>
```

Now it prints:

```
user = $.parseJSON('{"configuration":{"levels":{"warning":0.05,"danger":0.1}}}');
```

Links:
[Symfony 2 Docs - Output escaping](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#output-escaping)

Answer (score 6):

It is better to avoid using the `raw` filter when possible. You can here achieve the same behavior with the `escape` filter ([doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html)).

```
<script language="javascript">
    user = $.parseJSON('{{ userJSON | escape('js') }}');
</script>
```

Comment: gosh you just saved my life ! was trying 1000 solutions and in fact I just replaced "raw" by "escape('js')" and it worked fine ! Thx

Comment: Same for me ! even if the printed string is impossible to read for human, works like a charm